# show date in ranges in python graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have a linear regression which I want to have a fitting slope for, which would be in a graph whose independent variable would be
in date ranges, Please how can I modify the following code so that the date would be in ranges like

2022-01-30,2022-02-14, 2022-03-15, i.e. ranges would be in every three days.

This is my code

```
....
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

dict_data_confirm = {'2022-01-30': 50, '2022-01-31': 152, '2022-02-01': 41, '2022-02-02': 50,'2022-02-03': 50, '2022-02-04': 50,
'2022-02-05': 50, '2022-02-06': 50, '2022-02-07': 50, '2022-02-08': 50, '2022-02-09': 50, ......., '2022-09-30': 50, }



df = pd.Series(dict_data_confirm, name='Amount').rename_axis('Date').reset_index()

y=df.Amount

lr = LinearRegression()

datePd = pd.DataFrame({'time':df.Date, 'count':df.Amount})
x = pd.to_datetime(datePd.time)
lr.fit(x.values.reshape(-1,1), y)
plt.scatter(datePd.time, y, color='black')
lrValues = x.values.astype("float64").reshape(-1,1)
plt.plot(lrValues, lr.predict(lrValues), color='blue', linewidth=1)
plt.title('Purchase Data')
plt.ylabel('Amount')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.show()
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%y-%m-%d')) 
# Change the tick interval
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=15)) 
# Puts x-axis labels on an angle
plt.gca().xaxis.set_tick_params(rotation = 30)  
plt.gca().set_xbound('2020-01-30', '2020-05-11')
```

error output

```
    setattr(getattr(self.axes, lim_name), attr_name, (vmin, vmax))
File "C:\Users\my_system\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\transforms.py", line 990, in intervalx
self._points[:, 0] = interval
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array would exceed the maximum number of dimension of 1.
```

Comment: There is a lot going on in your code. You were plotting based on datetime in this line `plt.scatter(datePd.time, y, color='black')`. Then you are plotting datetime as floating number in the same plot `plt.plot(lrValues, lr.predict(lrValues), color='blue', linewidth=1)`. Which one are you looking to fix? Note that these two plots have very different x-axis.

Comment: @FanchenBao thanks for the reply. I am doing to plot one would be a scatter diagram and the next would be a slope of best fit

Comment: Hi, `plt.gca().set_xbound` takes floats, not strings, as arguments, what are you trying to achieve with this line?

Comment: @Laurent i want to draw a line of best fit around the scatter diagram

Answer (score 0):

Using `datetime` to train the linear regression model might not be the best idea. Instead, we can convert `datetime` to epoch timestamp for model training and prediction, but during plot, we stick to `datetime` for readability. The sample code is shown below (note: only the beginning portion of the original data is used).

```py
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd


dict_data_confirm = {'2022-01-30': 50, '2022-01-31': 152, '2022-02-01': 41, '2022-02-02': 50,'2022-02-03': 50, '2022-02-04': 50,
'2022-02-05': 50, '2022-02-06': 50, '2022-02-07': 50, '2022-02-08': 50, '2022-02-09': 50}

# prepare data
df = pd.Series(dict_data_confirm, name='Amount').rename_axis('Date').reset_index()
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)

# prepare linear regression model
lr = LinearRegression()
y= df.Amount
x = df.Date.apply(lambda x: x.timestamp())
lr.fit(x.to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1), y)

# plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(10, 8))
ax.scatter(df.Date, y, color='black')
ax.plot(df.Date, lr.predict(x.to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1)), color='blue', linewidth=1)

# config x-axis
ax.set_xticks(df.Date)
ax.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=45)

# set labels
ax.set_title('Purchase Data')
ax.set_ylabel('Amount')
ax.set_xlabel('Date')

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer.  I will try it out and get back. But looking at the best fit line, is that not wrong? I felt the line should be around the data points but yours is from the top more like a down slope?

Comment: Your data on 2022-01-31 is very outside the norm (most likely an outlier), which severely tilts the trend line. I include it because I don't have your full database to justify the removal of that data point. You can remove 2022-01-31 if it can be categorized as an outlier.